# how to display two graph using django-nvd3

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am using djano-nvd3 libraray for graph displaying in django. I have to display the two chart one for
linechart and another is piechart. the xdata[] and ydata[] for the linechart and xdata1[] and ydata1[] for piechart.

view.py

```
def demo_linechart_without_date(request):

extra_serie = {}
xdata = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
ydata = [3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1]
xdata1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
ydata1 = [3, 5, 7, 8, 3, 5, 3, 5, 7, 6, 3, 1]
chartdata = {
    'x': xdata,
    'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata, 'extra1': extra_serie,
}
chartdata1 = {
    'x': xdata1,
    'name1': 'series 1', 'y1': ydata1, 'extra1': extra_serie,
}
charttype = "lineChart"
charttype1 = "pieChart"
chartcontainer = 'linechart_container'
chartcontainer1 = 'linechart_container'# container name
data = {
    'charttype': charttype,
    'chartdata': chartdata,
    'chartcontainer': chartcontainer,
    'charttype1': charttype1,
    'chartdata1': chartdata1,
    'chartcontainer1': chartcontainer1,
    'extra': {
        'x_is_date': False,
        'x_axis_format': '',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
    },
    'extra1': {
        'x_is_date': False,
        'x_axis_format': '',
        'tag_script_js': True,
        'jquery_on_ready': False,
    }
}
return render_to_response('linechart.html', data)
```

linechart.html

```
  {% extends "base.html" %}
  {% block content %}
  {% load nvd3_tags %}
 <head>
{% include_chart_jscss %}
{% if date_tag %}
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer  True "%d %b %Y %H" %}
    {% load_chart charttype1 chartdata1 chartcontainer1  True "%d %b %Y %H" %}
{% else %}
    {% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer extra  %}
    {% load_chart charttype1 chartdata1 chartcontainer1 extra1  %}
{% endif %}
 </head>
 <body>
  {% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}
{% include_container chartcontainer1 400 600 %}
 </body>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with your code.

> chartcontainer = 'linechart_container' 
>   chartcontainer1 = 'linechart_container'# container name

if you look at the html code from your generated "linechart.html", there should be two divs with identical id:

> div id="linechart_container"

so I would suggest you change

> chartcontainer1 = 'linechart_container'  (from view.py)

to:

> chartcontainer1 = 'linechart_container1'

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

`{% extends "base.html" %}`

`{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}`

`{% load static %}`

`{% block content %}`

`<div class="col-sm-6">`

`{% load_chart charttype chartdata chartcontainer %}
 {% include_container chartcontainer 400 600 %}`

`</div>`

`<div class="col-sm-6">`

```
{% load_chart charttype1 chartdata1 chartcontainer1 %}
{% include_container chartcontainer1 400 600 %}
```

`</div>`

{% endblock %}